# Solve for $x: 2^{\sin x+1}+2^{\cos x+1}=2^{3x^2-2x^3}$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, inequality

> Solve for $x: 2^{\sin x+1}+2^{\cos x+1}=2^{3x^2-2x^3}$

**Attempt $1:$**

$$2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}=2^{3x^2-2x^3-1}$$

Applying AM-GM inequality.

$$\frac{2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}}2\ge\sqrt{2^{\sin x+\cos x}}\\\implies 2^{3x^2-2x^3-2}\ge2^{-\frac1{\sqrt2}}$$

Not able to proceed from here.

**Attempt $2:$**

$\sin x$ minimum value is $-1$. Here, $\cos x$ will be zero.

Thus, minimum of $2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}$ is $\frac52$

Similarly, maximum is $5$

Therefore, $$\frac52\le2^{3x^2-2x^3-1}\le5$$

Not able to proceed from here.

**The answer given is No Solution.**

Comment: According to Mathematica, there is a unique root. Not sure that there is analytical expression for this root.

Comment: Since $2^{3x^2-2x^3}\to 0$ when $x\to +\infty $ and $\to +\infty $ when $x\to -\infty $, and that $1\leq 2^{\sin(x)+1}+2^{\cos(x)+1}\leq 10$, obviously, you equation has at least one solution. Can you find it by hand ? that's an other story...

Comment: Your reasoning in the attempt 2 is wrong. The minimum is $2\cdot 2^{-1/\sqrt 2}$ achieved at $x=\frac{5}{4} \pi$

Comment: @aarbee There is an unique root on $(-1,-0.5).$ Maybe it means $x\geq-\frac{1}{2}$? If so, your equation has no real roots.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks. I had posted the question verbatim. Maybe there's an error in the book.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a trascendental equation for which you must try with numerical approximation. After division you have the function
$$f(x)=2^{\sin(x)+(x-1)^2(2x+1)}+2^{\cos(x)+(x-1)^2(2x+1)}$$ and you have to calculate $x$ such that $f(x)=1$ for a continuous function whose minimum in the first quadrant is greater than $1$ then the solution is in the negative real.

You do have a function $f$ increasing in the interval $[-1,0]$ such that $f(-1)=0.125....$ and $f(0)=6$ so the required value is in $[-1,0]$. A much better approximation you can get is with  $f(-0.7)=1.0496....$ and
$f(-0.8)=0.5793....$ so you search in the interval $[-0.8,-0.7]$ and so on till you are satisfied with your approximation.